# Name of Record Type in formula

Tags: apex, formula

Is there an opportunity to get the name of Record Type of created record in formula for example ?r

For example
I have 3 records types Ac1, Ac2, Ac3 and 3 page layouts for them.

When I choose record type Ac1 I would like to see on page layout name of this record type. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can reference data on a parent object (such as RecordType) in a formula, much in the same way you can with a SOQL query (by using dot notation).

`RecordType.Name`

Of course, if you simply include the recordType field on the page layout, you get this for free. No need to create a new field (unless you want to use the record type name in a trigger without performing an extra query, in which case the formula field would be the way to go).